# compare safety of two kinds ssh forwarding

Tags: ssh, portforwarding

I've got three servers, HC(home client), ECS(elastic computing server), TS(target server). TS has a whitelist containing Ip of ECS but not HC, hence a proper way for HC to login to TS is through ssh forwarding. I got both two kinds of ssh forwarding method to work below,

#### Method I: make a tunnel between HC and ECS:

on HC: **ssh -L HC_Port:TS_Ip:22 ECS**

command **ssh -p HC_Port 127.0.0.1** on HC works to ssh login to TS

#### Method II: make a tunnel between ECS and TS:

on HC: **ssh -L 0.0.0.0:ECS_Port:127.0.0.1:22 ECS**

command **ssh -p ECS_Port ECS_Ip** on HC also works to ssh login to TS

Suppose some sensitive data is transmitted through ssh within a tunnel, which method is more safe and provider of ECS is not that easy to get the decrypted data. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I believe Method I is a better choice. The key pair to encrypt and decrypt data transmitted between home client and target server is **absolutly unknown** to the elastic computing server. while Method II isn't.